# Looking for std container between map and list

Tags: c++, containers, std

Looking for a container, that stores elements under custom key (like a map), allows searching under the key in better complexity, then O(n) (like a map), but also remembers the order in which pairs (key and value) were inserted, allowing for push_front and pop_back functionality, like in the list

**edit:** Solved simply using both containers. Map for storing  pairs and list for storing the indexes in order. Will leave this question open if someone comes with more elegant solution.

Comment: you could use [multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) although the syntax is a bit gnarly

Comment: There is no standard container that is both sorted and remembers the unsorted order. You could build a simple version of the multiindex by using the map for storage and fast searching, while also storing the keys in a deque (supports push_front and pop_back). Assuming that fast search is the most important.

Comment: c++11 has std::unsorted_map, which does exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such data structure in the standard library.

A "trivial" way to implement such structure would be to use two separate structures internally. A map for lookup, and a list (or a vector, or a deque) for iterating in insertion order. One of the data structures should store the objects, and the other can store pointers to the objects.

There is a generalization of this kind of multi-index container in the [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) library collection.

Comment: I think a list would be better than a vector, because list iterators are never invalidated, so you could keep the iterators in the map.

Comment: @alain Or you could store the objects in the map and iterators in the vector in which case that is not a problem. Although, you still end up missing the best benefit of a vector that is the contiguity of memory.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility.